# Add html div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This is my html structure. I want to create a div using jQuery.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-1">
    </div>
    <div class="main-2">
    </div>
    <div class="main-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

My expected output will contain another div with `class="main-1" and class="main-2"`

It should look like :-

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="newadd">
        <div class="main-1">
        </div>
        <div class="main-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, `newadd` is the new class which need to add. I can select the main div using :-

```
jQuery(".main");
```

But, I am not sure how to add an extra div in-between existent divs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.wrapAll()` :

```js
$('.main .wrapMe').wrapAll("<div class='newadd' />")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-1 wrapMe">a
    </div>
    <div class="main-2 wrapMe">b
    </div>
    <div class="main-3">c
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

User [wrapall](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```
$('.main-1, .main-2,').wrapAll('<div class="newadd" />');
```

**Output**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="newadd">
        <div class="main-1">
        </div>
   <div class="newadd">
        <div class="main-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-3">
    </div>
</div>
```